# Let $a$ be a zero of $f(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ in some extension field of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$. Find the other zero of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}(\alpha)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Proof:**

If $ax^2+bx+c: a \neq 0$ is a quadratic polynomial and $\alpha,\beta$ are the roots of the polynomial $f(x)$ then $\alpha+\beta= \frac{-b}{a}$ and $\alpha\beta=\frac{c}{a}$. Now, consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ and consider that $\alpha$ be a zero of $f(x)$ in some extension $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[\alpha]$. We are tasked with finding the other zero of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[\alpha]$. For this, lets consider that $\beta$ is the root of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[\alpha]$. Now, since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $f(x)$. Then, $\alpha+\beta=-1 \equiv -1 \mod 5= 4$ and $\alpha\beta=1 \equiv 1 \mod 5 = 1$.

I'm stuck here

Comment: The key words: "in $\mathbb{Z}_5(\alpha)$".  So, you're allowed to give an expression for $\beta$ as a rational function of $\alpha$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: I mean I can see that $\beta=4-\alpha \vee \beta = 4+4\alpha$ but how does this help me?

Comment: Did you see that $\beta = 4 - \alpha = -1 - \alpha$, and $\beta =4(1 + \alpha) =-1(1 + \alpha) = -1 -\alpha$; so the results are the same.  In $\Bbb Z_5$, of course . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $\beta = -1-\alpha$. Then
$$\alpha\beta = \alpha(-1-\alpha) = -\alpha^2-\alpha = 1 $$
since $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$. Also,
$$ (-1-\alpha)^2+(-1-\alpha)+1 = 1+2\alpha+\alpha^2-1-\alpha+1 = \alpha^2+\alpha+1 = 0. $$
Hence $-1-\alpha$ is the other root.